# is it possible to deploy a website without buying a domain?

Tags: internet, ip, webserver, domain

I've just started learning client-side web languages and I'm about to deploy a 'test' website just for experience. However, as I said, since this is just to get more training I don't actually want to buy a domain name. my question is, can I publicize a website without actually buying a domain and instead the user will just access it through an IP address?

Comment: "just access it through an IP address?" - Yes, if the user knows your ip address, and you have configured a web server, then the user would be served content.

Comment: @Ramhound you forget the most important part, port forwarding.

Comment: @LPChip - I considered that part of the configuring the web server.  Won't even get into the fact, every domain is basically an ip address, DNS exists so we don't have to type out `xxx.kkk.yyy.zzz` every time we visit SU.

Comment: so... any practical solutions?

Comment: @Maslin - Just properly configure your web server client.  How you configure your website to say respond at 127.0.0.1 is no different then any the ip address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you do not need to buy a domain, all you need is an accessible IP address.  In reality, all websites are accessed by IP, not by name.  When you type a name into your browser, your computer does a DNS query of the name to get it's IP address.  In order for people to get to your website, they just need to type in the IP address.  If the website is not running on the default port of 80, they will have to add the port number at the end of the address with a colon.  For example: `http://1.2.3.4:8080`

Comment: No, you dont need a static IP.  However, every time your IP changes, you will have to inform the users of your site that it changed.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. You should be able to do that through XAMMP/WAMP. You will need to run the system constantly, and have your ports open. I typically wouldn't recommend, but for quick easy testing you could. Domains are very cheap, shouldn't be more than 13 annually.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a local web server setup on your machine, it's possible to expose your website to the internet using services like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/). It will allow remote access to web server using their sub domains (e.g. 2w9c34maz.ngrok.io) for a period of time.